# Pandas rolling function fails with "Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1"

Tags: python, pandas

In the following example, I'm trying to calculate the 3-month moving average of values grouped by country using pandas rolling function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country':  ['US','US','US','US', 'US', 'US', 'FR','FR','FR','FR'],
    'year': [1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993],
    'gdp': [1.2, 1.4, 1.7, 2.1, 2.3, 1.9, 4.1, 4.6, 4.3, 4.4]
})

print(df)

     country    year    gdp
0    US         1990    1.2
1    US         1991    1.4
2    US         1992    1.7
3    US         1993    2.1
4    US         1994    2.3
5    US         1995    1.9
6    FR         1990    4.1
7    FR         1991    4.6
8    FR         1992    4.3
9    FR         1993    4.4

df['ma'] = df.groupby('country', as_index=False)['gdp'].rolling(3,min_periods=1).mean()
```

Throws the following error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Where am I passing 2 items instead of 1?

Comment: When you groupby the aggregated result may not have same number of records and key as original df. If you wish to join, provide have some criteria to join with original df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When computing the rolling/groupby a second level of index is added, which you don't need here and is preventing the correct assignment. Drop it with `droplevel`, not using the `as_index=False` option that moves it to column:

```
df['ma'] = df.groupby('country')['gdp'].rolling(3,min_periods=1).mean().droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
  country  year  gdp        ma
0      US  1990  1.2  1.200000
1      US  1991  1.4  1.300000
2      US  1992  1.7  1.433333
3      US  1993  2.1  1.733333
4      US  1994  2.3  2.033333
5      US  1995  1.9  2.100000
6      FR  1990  4.1  4.100000
7      FR  1991  4.6  4.350000
8      FR  1992  4.3  4.333333
9      FR  1993  4.4  4.433333
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
print(df.groupby('country', as_index=False)['gdp'].rolling(3,min_periods=1).mean())

  country       gdp
6      FR  4.100000
7      FR  4.350000
8      FR  4.333333
9      FR  4.433333
0      US  1.200000
1      US  1.300000
2      US  1.433333
3      US  1.733333
4      US  2.033333
5      US  2.100000
```

This result returns 2 columns and 1 index. That's why it cannot be assign to 1 column in your `df`.

Quick fix for problem:

```py
df['ma'] = df.groupby('country', as_index=False)['gdp'].rolling(3,min_periods=1).mean()['gdp']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `rolling()` but I caught an error. It can return 2 Columns in a dataframe but you can provide only one column `df['ma']`. You can use this to avoid an error.

```
df[['item1','item2']] = df.groupby('country', as_index=False)['gdp'].rolling(3,min_periods=1).mean()
```

It can show output like this:

[image]